# Magic file format

Tags: man, file-types

From the [magic file format manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) the format for the rule should be

```
offset type value message
```

For example:

```
0      string   MZ
>0x18  leshort  <0x40   MS-DOS executable
>0x18  leshort  >0x3f   extended PC executable (e.g., MS Windows)
```

Using this context, I am trying to understand magic file such as [this one](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/measure) which has rules like

```
# DIY-Thermocam raw data
0   name    diy-thermocam-parser
>0  beshort x   scale %d-
```

What does the first rule mean? name is not a valid type from the man page at least. And there is no test component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at a manpage that isn't for the version of software you're looking at

The manpage from the `doc` directory at that github site says:

```
          name        Define a ``named'' magic instance that can be called
                      from another use magic entry, like a subroutine
                      call.  Named instance direct magic offsets are rela-
                      tive to the offset of the previous matched entry,
                      but indirect offsets are relative to the beginning
                      of the file as usual.  Named magic entries always
                      match.
```